# What is the book about a teen girl and guy who are stuck in a game where they can die and she has to complete every level in order to survive?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book about two or three years ago and I forgot the name.

It was about a teen girl who didn't have much, she was poor, and she was in foster care, so she ran away and was living in the streets. I'm pretty sure that her parents died but I'm not sure. She woke up in a room and she didn't know where she was. She found another teen boy, and then she found out that she was in this weird underground TV show thing where there are people who subscribe and watch to see two contestants try to fight it out and complete each level of a game without dying. it usually was just one contestant but it was different this year. There are people who pay to watch this show; I'm pretty sure it was illegal and that it was like a black market business.

One of the games was where they had to go on top of a tall skyscraper and they had to walk from the roof of one building to the roof of another on a really thin pathway. The games that they played were really dangerous and could lead to death, but people still paid to watch. I'm pretty sure there was another game where they had to fight these guys. The two teens ended up liking each other. Later she found out that the guy's father was the creator and the head of the game and that he put himself in the game to rebel against his father, and they tried to make a way to end the game/TV show. this book was set during the time the book was released or maybe a few years later, it never specified the year but it seemed like it was pretty similar to how everything is now.

That's all I remember but I need help finding the book.

Comment: Sounds a lot like Hunger Games but some of the details don't match

Comment: @MBEllis You and i recall a very different version of Hunger Games.

Comment: @GamerGypps- I am just saying they have the same principal-  a poor orphan teenage girl is in a fighting show on TV  fighting teens to death, the girl likes another boy and they try to stop the games

Comment: @MBEllis - Katniss was not orphaned. Her father had died, sure, but not her mother.

Comment: yea it is definitely not hunger games there weren't other people that had to be part of the game show it was just them two